# reconcile infinity in cardinality and infinity in limit

Tags: real-analysis

In Abbott's Understanding Analysis there was question to prove that set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}=\{a_1,a_2,...\}$ has measure zero. For given $\epsilon>0$, let $O_n=(a_n-\epsilon_n,a_n+\epsilon_n)$ where $\epsilon_n=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}$. 
 Then $\{O_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ covers $\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|O_n|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n}}=\epsilon$. My question is up until now, I understand infinity in cardinality and infinity in taking limits as two different concepts. However in the above proof, it seems that the reason we take the limit of the sum as $n \to \infty$ is because the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is countably infinite. So are these two concepts of infinity actually related and the same?

Comment: The notion of _countably infinite_ comes first.  Then the definition of a measure includes the _countable additivity_ axiom $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n) = \mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)$ for disjoint measurable sets $\{A_n\}$.  From this the _union bound_ can be derived, which says $\mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$ for any collection of measurable sets $A_n$.   So countably infinite sums are allowed and are used in the definition of measure. We do not sum over an uncountably infinite number of terms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)

Comment: I do not see the carnality of $\mathbb N$ being involved though.. Those $n$ are ordinals, used to denote $a_1,a_2, ..., a_n,...$

Answer (score 1):

The cardinality of $\mathbb N$ and an infinite sequence are certainly related. After all, any set that can be put into a sequence has a cardinality (at most) $\aleph_0$. However, it is right to say that the infinity that you put on top of the summation sign is a distinct concept from the cardinal number $\aleph_0.$

I wouldn't say that "the reason we take the limit ... is because the cardinality of $\mathbb N$ is countably infinite." We consider the infinite sum because it helps us show what we intend to show, namely that for any $\epsilon>0$ the measure of the integers is less than or equal to $\epsilon$ (which in turn implies that it's zero).

The reason that the infinite sequence of open intervals is chosen is that each one can cover each integer. This has everything to do with the integers' countability. And then the other key thing is that the widths are chosen to decrease with $n$ so that the sum of lengths of the intervals is finite. The icing on the cake is that measures are (by definition) countably additive, which means $$\mu(\bigcup_n A_n)\le \sum_n\mu(A_n) $$ for any *countable* union.

Note that actually this same proof will work to prove that *any* countable subset of the reals has measure $0.$

As I said before, sequences (which are what infinite sums are based on) are highly tied to the cardinality of the natural numbers in that they have that cardinality or less when demoted to sets.  But just because countability plays a role in the proof and so do infinite sums doesn't mean that the infinities in the two are the same notion.

The concept having cardinality $\aleph_0$ is about one-to-one correspondence to the integers. The notion of a limit of an infinite sequence is about properties (like $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$) holding true for all sufficiently large $n$. Note that this isn't really tied to the cardinality of the integers. For one, we can formulate $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ for real $x$ (and recall the reals have a different cardinality than the naturals). This concept of infinite limit is really about the order on the sets ($\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$) and the fact that they have no greatest element.

Comment: To paraphase the part you don't understand, the point is that things like $\lim_{x \to \aleph_0}$ or $\sum_{n=0}^{\aleph_0}$ don't really make sense at all in the context of ordinary calculus; the extended real number $+\infty$ that is used in these places has nothing to do with cardinality.

Comment: @Hurkyl I figured it was something like that. Did I capture that in my last paragraph there about the latter infinity having to do with ordered sets with no upper bound? I didn't mention the extended real number notion, but I think it fits in with that.